# How to generate some identically distributed pseudo-random vectors with a fixed length r in a programming language?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, random

For example, for the dimension `d=2`, it means that we could generate a random angle `0<=a<2*pi`, and then we could just use

`(x_1,x_2)=(r*cos(a),r*sin(a))` as the random vector.

However, for the dimension `d>=3`, we could not just generate an angle and use it to represent the vector. Then how could we generate such a vector `(x_1,...,x_d)`, which is identically distributed on `x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_d^2=r^2`?

---

I have just come up with a new idea, that we could generate a vector `(x_1,...,x_d)` such that `-r<=x_i<r` for all `i`, normalize it if `x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_d^2<=r^2` and abondon it if `x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_d^2>r^2`.

However, there is a drawback that the probability that `x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_d^2<=r^2` would become very small if `d` is very large. Does there exist some better solutions?

Comment: Do you just want to know it for 3 dimensions or do you want a general case answer for n-dimensions?

Comment: If fact I would like to know about the general case, since I may use a 1000-dimension vector...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate random variables (X_1, X_2, ... X_d) that are independent and have standard normal distributions, and then normalize by dividing by  sqrt(X_1^2+...+X_d^2)/r.

That the joint distribution of independent normal distributions is rotationally symmetric is not just true, it characterizes normal distributions.

You can generate pairs of independent variables with a standard normal distribution efficiently from uniform random variables using the [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform).

Comment: Could it get a distribution which is same at each directions?

Comment: @Tianyi Hao: The multivariate normal distribution is invariant under all rotations. It looks the same from each direction. If you generate each coordinate from a non-normal distribution, then the joint distribution will not look the same from each direction.

Comment: @Douglas - upvoting: Wolfram agrees http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html; this is also the accepted answer on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136314/what-is-a-good-method-to-find-random-points-on-the-n-sphere-when-n-is-large and other sites.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways around it.

The straightforward way is, in pseudo-code:

```
1. build n-dimensional vector x[0] through x[n-1] with random components
2. find radius
3. go to step 1 if radius > r; otherwise, normalize to radius r
```

This is non-deterministic, because there is no way to know how many times you will need to cycle before you find an acceptable sphere. Additionally, the probability of finding a bad point goes up with the number of dimensions.

To understand why (thanks commenters!), imagine a 1x1 square. Add a r=1 circle inside. Fill the square with random points. All the points between the center and the circle are evenly distributed when projected on the circle. All the points between the circle and the square's border are not - because there's too many at, say, 45º; and none at, say, 90º.

The non-straightforward version is a generalization of your 2-dimensional approach:

```
1. assume that we are on an n-sphere; generate angles phi[0], ...phi[n-2] 
   for a polar-coordinates point
2. convert to cartesian coordinates x[0] through x[n-1]
```

According to the [n-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) page in wikipedia, the formula is

```
x[0]   = r*cos(phi[0]);
x[1]   = r*sin(phi[0])*cos(phi[1]);
x[2]   = r*sin(phi[0])*sin(phi[1]);
...
x[n-2] = r*sin(phi[0])*sin(phi[1])* /*...*/ sin(phi[n-3])*sin(phi[n-2])
x[n-1] = r*sin(phi[0])*cos(phi[1])* /*...*/ sin(phi[n-3])*cos(phi[n-2])
```

The actual algorithm can be implemented a lot more efficiently (`sin(phi[0]`) is getting calculated a lot, for example)

To avoid non-determinism, I recommend the second approach.

**Edit**

The recommended approach, not listed above, is in Douglas's answer and many reference sites:

- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136314/what-is-a-good-method-to-find-random-points-on-the-n-sphere-when-n-is-large
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html

Comment: For the straightforward way, would the densities of the vectors the same on different directions? For example, the density near `(1,0,0)` and the ones near `(1,1,1)`.

Comment: You are right - only method 2 is good currently good. Fixing above.

Comment: You can't just generate the coordinates randomly from any distribution, you need to use a normal distribution if you want the result to be spherically symmetric. (Maxwell's theorem.) For your second method, how are you ensuring that the distribution is uniform?

Comment: Thanks @DouglasZare and OP - I have rewritten that part of the answer, adding a step-3 in the initial algorithm, and marking it non-deterministic.

Comment: @DouglasZare default floating-point random generators for C++ and Java return uniformly-distributed numbers between 0 and 1, so no extra work is needed to ensure uniformity in individual numbers. There are exactly n-1 degrees of liberty for each point, so I am ready to bet that the final point is randomly distributed on the surface. Can you provide a counter-argument?

Comment: That the random number generators produce numbers that are approximately evenly distributed on the interval does not mean that whatever you do with them will produce evenly distributed numbers on other sets. For example, if you take (X_1,...,X_d) and divide each coordinate by sqrt(X_1^2+...+X_d^2) then you don't get a uniform distribution on the sphere. Everything would be in the first quadrant, and you would overweight a small region around (1/sqrt(d),1/sqrt(d),...,1/sqrt(d)) relative to a congruent region near (1,0,0,...,0).

Comment: Your answer says to "generate angles phi[0]...phi[n-2]" but if you take points uniformly distributed on a 2- or higher-dimensional sphere, those angles are not uniformly distributed. One classic result is that as the dimension increases, the proportion of the sphere close (within a fixed epsilon) to any equatorial hypersphere goes to 1. It's definitely not the case that half of the points in the upper hemisphere are within 45 degrees of the north pole. Therefore, if you choose a uniform distribution on the spherical angles, you get a nonuniform distribution on the sphere.